# Varnish: Cache all content until a certain date?

Tags: varnish

Is there a way I can configure Varnish to store everything under a certain path until a date that I set?

My site updates once a month, so I'd simply like to serve cached content until then.

Comment: I dont think we can cache the content on Varnish by specifying Date pattern.But you can specify the number of days you want the content to be cached in the TTL Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add header field

```
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
```

to every response. And of course set the date to the end of the month. Varnish should honor this header field. And be sure to remove all cache control headers that could disable caching (max-age, no-cache, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

On Varnish 7.4, I'm using this to make all the cached content expire at tomorrow midnight (GMT for easiness):

```
set beresp.ttl = (std.time(regsub(now, "^(.+?)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(.+?)$", "\100:00:00\2")) + 1d - now);
```

What it does:

1. `now` when used as a STRING is converted to a text like 'Tue, 20 Feb 2018 09:30:31 GMT' ([docs](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.4/reference/vcl-var.html#special-variables))
2. `regsub(<#1>, "^(.+?)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(.+?)$", "\100:00:00\2")` replaces the time portion with 00:00:00, so that's today midnight
3. `std.time(<#2>)` converts the time from STRING to TIME type, so that it can be used in time arithmetics
4. `<#3> + 1d - now` turns today midnight into tomorrow midnight and computes the remaining seconds to it, obtaining a value for `beresp.ttl`

Still testing it but I'm actually getting an Age: 3872 for a page I initially requested a couple of hours before midnight, so I'm positive about it.

Answer (score -1):

Set a ttl = 30 days and Varnish will serve the exact same object  for 30 days.